# Knockout.js nested with and options binding removing select from DOM

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Good morning people. I'm playing a little bit with knockout.js, I'm trying to do a cascade filtering on a couple of drop downs. Lets say I have 3 tables,

Groups -> Subgroups -> Sectors

And when groups is selected, the subgruoup drop down is filtered and then when the subgroup drop down is selected the sectors is filtered by the subgroup value. You get the picture.

I have this code already.

HTMl:

```
<div class="span3">
 <label for="grupos">Grupo<i clasS="icon-search"></i></label>
 <select class="span12" id="grupos" data-bind="value:grupo">
    <option value="1" >A</option>
    <option value="2" >B</option>
    <option value="3" >C</option>
 </select>
</div>
<div class="span3">
  <label for="subgrupos">Subgrupo</label>
  <!-- ko with: grupo -->
  <select class="span12" id="subgrupos" data-bind='options:$parent.subgrupoData,            optionsText: "description", optionsCaption: "Select...", optionsValue: "id", value: $parent.subgrupo'> </select>
   <!-- /ko -->
  </div>
  <div class="span3">
    <label for="secciones">Seccion</label>
 <!-- ko with: subgrupo -->
    <select class="span12" id="secciones" data-bind='options:$parent.seccionData, optionsText: "description", optionsCaption: "Select...", optionsValue: "id", value: $parent.seccion'>
    </select>
    <!-- /ko -->
 </div>
```

And the JS:

var Subgroup = function(_id, _description) {
        var self = this;
        self.id = _id;
        self.description = _description;
    };

```
var Section = function(_id, _description) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = _id;
    self.description = _description;
};


var SearchModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.grupo = ko.observable();
    self.subgrupo = ko.observable();
    self.subgrupoData = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.seccion = ko.observable();
    self.seccionData = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.grupo.subscribe(function() {
        $.getJSON("/someurl", {'g':$('#grupos').val()}, function(data) {
            var mappedSg = $.map(data, function(item) { return new Subgroup(item.id, item.description) });
            self.subgrupoData(mappedSg);
        });
        self.seccion(undefined);
    });

    self.subgrupo.subscribe(function() {
        if($('#subgrupos')){
            $.getJSON("/anotherurl", {'sg':$('#subgrupos').val()}, function(data) {
                var mappedSect = $.map(data, function(item) { return new Section(item.id, item.description) });
                self.seccionData(mappedSect);
            });
        }else{
            self.seccion(undefined);
        }
    });
};
ko.applyBindings(new SearchModel());
```

So I got the work done, but I have to write the if ($('#subgrupos')) validation because if I change the first drop down, the second is changed and so, the third is making a search without an id.

My question is, is there a way to avoid that the selects with a "with" binding being remove from the DOM? And the validation is there a "knockout" way to validate that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question, you can remove the jquery selectors from your javascript to fix the problem. Your knockout subscribe handlers do accept the new value of the observable as the first parameter.

In response to your validation question, take a look at the [Knockout Validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) library.

Here is the  revised javascript to solve your first issue:

```
var Section = function(_id, _description) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = _id;
    self.description = _description;
};


var SearchModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.grupo = ko.observable();
    self.subgrupo = ko.observable();
    self.subgrupoData = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.seccion = ko.observable();
    self.seccionData = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.grupo.subscribe(function(newGrupo) {
        $.getJSON("/someurl", {'g':newGrupo}, function(data) {
            var mappedSg = $.map(data, function(item) { return new Subgroup(item.id, item.description) });
            self.subgrupoData(mappedSg);
        });
        self.seccion(undefined);
    });

    self.subgrupo.subscribe(function(newSubGrupo) {
        if($('#subgrupos')){
            $.getJSON("/anotherurl", {'sg':newSubGrupo}, function(data) {
                var mappedSect = $.map(data, function(item) { return new Section(item.id, item.description) });
                self.seccionData(mappedSect);
            });
        }else{
            self.seccion(undefined);
        }
    });
};
ko.applyBindings(new SearchModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use knockout extenders.. just have look at the documentation on how to use that : [Knockout Extenders](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html). Scroll down on that page and they have explained how to use validators using extenders.

Comment: Given that the knockout validation library is built using extenders and also contains many pre-defined validation rules, that would be a better option.